# How many Stephanotis species in cultivation, and how diverse?

Tags: identification

Mostly, [I get species names with no links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanotis). Pictures on the web mostly belong to S. Floribunda, the only Stephanotis I see in cultivation. One or two pictures I may have encountered, look similar enough to be mistaken with it as well.

How diverse is the Stephanotis species?

Can it be hybridized with Hoya?